# kafka asynchronous produce lost message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Try to follow the instruction on internet to achieve kafka asynchronous produce. Here is what my producer looks like:

```java
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
public void asynSend(String topic, Integer partition, String message) {
    ProducerRecord<Object, Object> data = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, partition,null, message);
        producer.send(data, new DefaultProducerCallback());
    }

private static class DefaultProducerCallback implements Callback {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
        if (e != null) {
            logger.error("Asynchronous produce failed");
        }
    }
}
```

And I produce in a for loop like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    int partition = i % 2;
    FsProducerFactory.getInstance().asynSend(topic, partition,i + "th message to partition " + partition);
}
```

However, some message may get lost. As shown below, message from 4508 to 4999 not delivered.

[image]

I find the reason might be the shutdown of producer process and all message in cache not send at that time would be lost.
Add this line after for loop would solve this problem:

```java
producer.flush();
```

However, I am not sure whether it is a charm solution because I notice someone mentioned that flush would make Asynchronous send somehow Synchronous, can anyone explain or help me improve it?

Answer (score 0):

In the book `Kafka - The definitive Guide` there is an example for an asznchronous Producer given exactly as you have written the code. It uses `send` together with a `Callback`.

In a [discussion](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/137) it is written:

> Adding `flush()` before exiting will make the client wait for any outstanding messages to be delivered to the broker (and this will be around `queue.buffering.max.ms`, plus latency).
>   If you add `flush()` after each `produce()` call you are effectively implementing a sync producer.

But if you do it *after* the `for` loop it is not synchronous anymore but rather asynchronous.

What you could do also do is to set the `acks` in the Producer configuration to `all`. That way you will have some more guarantees to successfully produce messages in case the replication of the topic is set to greater than 1.

Comment: thx mike, `flush()` now seems  not a bad choice to keep producer alive and get all message delivered in my scenario. I also tried   `acks` which you suggest but did not work.

Comment: Have you checked all partitions to see if all data was produced? In your screenshot it only shows partition 1 but nothing about partition 0. Keep in mind that the order could be different over partitions.

Comment: my consumer thread polls every 100ms and consume about  800 messages each poll. So there is 800 messages in a row in the output for a specific partition, followed by 800 messages for another partition. I am sure that data of both partition was produced, but none of each was fully delivered.